# What will be the correct output?

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I want to implement the following equation given in a paper “A Three-Layered Mutually Reinforced Model for
Personalized Citation Recommendation” (Page 4). According to the description in the paper, B should be a square matrix, whereas I am getting a vector.

[image]

I have tried the following code:

```
querySplit = query.split(',')
queryText = querySplit[0]
qt_tag = word_tokenize(queryText.rstrip().lower().translate(translator))
qt_vector = model.infer_vector(qt_tag)

def eq_b(query):
    vecs = np.asarray(
        [spatial.distance.cosine(spatial.distance.cosine(query, model.docvecs[i]), model.docvecs[i]) for i in
         range(Docs_len)])
    return vecs / vecs.sum()

b = eq_b(qt_vector)
print("B", b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you wrote for B is not correct. From the paper, B*Rt_p is **equal** to what you have, but not B itself. This means that the actual formula for the matrix is:

`B=np.matmul(eq_b(qt_vector),transpose(Rt_p))/norm(Rt_p)^2`

You basically add that extra stuff so that when you do the multiplication with `Rt_p`, all the terms involving `Rt_p` are cancelled and you are left with `eq_b(qt_vector)`. The cancellation is due to the fact that

`transpose(Rt_p)*Rt_p ==norm(Rt_p)^2`

Comment: As far as I can see, the formula in the paper is correct. What I am saying is that B*R^(t)_pj  == the "B" formula that you posted as an image (which is indeed a vector). If you take the B that i wrote, and multiply it by Rt_p, you will get eq_b(qt_vector) (transpose(R^(t)_pj)*R^(t)_pj/norm(Rt_p)^2

Comment: edited so that Rt_p is transposed in the matrix multiplication

Comment: could you please tell me one more thing that in these equations what will be the value of R^(t)_pj? I have used values from a randomly initiated positive vector with l2-norm equal to one (as mentioned in algorithm pp 4). Is it correct or there will be some other way to get value of R^(t)_pj for Mpp?

Comment: It seems that you are trying to converge to a fixed point. Try different values and see if it gives you the same result. My intuition says that if you somehow have a good guess for the fixed point value then you will converge faster if you use that info.

Comment: Dear @Juan Carlos Ramirez, I am getting incorrect output. eq_b(qt_vector) is returning me a row vector, whereas I need a column vector. If I am using eq_b(qt_vector) and Rp_t as row vectors then I am getting a single value. Please, help me in it. Here is my code

Comment: d = 0.85
querySplit = query.split(',')
queryText = querySplit[0]
qt_tag = word_tokenize(queryText.rstrip().lower().translate(translator))
qt_vector = model.infer_vector(qt_tag)

def eq_b(query):
    vecs = np.asarray(
        [spatial.distance.cosine(spatial.distance.cosine(query, model.docvecs[i]), model.docvecs[i]) for i in
         range(Docs_len)])
    return vecs / vecs.sum()
Rp = np.random.rand(Docs_len, 1)

norm_Rp = LA.norm(Rp, 2)
Rt_p = np.true_divide(Rp, norm_Rp)

B = np.matmul(eq_b(qt_vector),np.transpose(Rt_p))/pow(LA.norm(Rt_p), 2)

Comment: def eq_c(wpp):
    return (wpp / wpp.sum(axis=0)).sum()
C = eq_c(Wpp)

Mpp = np.transpose (d * B + (1 - d) * C)